# Запутался в reshape

Tags: python, numpy

Всем привет, запутался в reshape. У меня есть вот такой массив

```
X_train.shape
(825, 3, 1)
```

Нужно перевести его в форму как на картинке. Пытался сделать `X_train.reshape(825, 3, 3)` выдает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда возьмутся лишние данные? Перемножение всех размеров должно оставаться константой - ведь число элементов в итоге должно остаться таким же как и было, меняется только пространственная форма массива. Попробуйте `X_train.reshape(275, 3, 3)` что ли.

Comment: Спс, кажется понял в каком направлении думать.